# How many time series is it logical to model using VAR (in R)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, prediction

I have weekly sales for around 6000 `products`, for which I would like to obtain forecasts for `n` periods. I believe that estimate forecasts for all 6000 `products` is too much, so i thought about aggregating the products in certain categories/clusters (based on some rules).

I end up with around 50 `products` (or more correct groups/clusters of `products`), for which again I want forecasts for `n` periods.

My question is, are 50 products again too many for a VAR model ? I am planning on using the `vars` package in R

Or maybe it would be a better idea to estimate 50 VAR models (because 50 is the groups/clusters of `products`), with the logic that since the products in each group are similar, then the sales of a `product will` affect the sales of a product (in the same category)

Comment: How many observations are you planning on using?  Do your weekly observations go back for several years?

Comment: the total number of observations for each group of products is around 150, so it is a bit more than 2 years

Comment: Why do you believe 50 factors would be too many? Are you concerned about computation constraints or viability of results?

Comment: i never used VAR before so i dont really know. Moreover if you have 50 groups and you add lag order of 1, then multicollinearity can be an issue, right ?